# OperationalError: near ":1": syntax error in SQLite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have this error.

My Table column names are as followed after i performed join and union:

```
['A','B','C','B:1','D','B:2','E']
```

In order to drop/rename the Table columns, I executed this query:

```
query = '''
        CREATE TABLE New_Table
        ['A','B_a','C','B_b','D','B_c','E']
        '''
query1 = '''
        INSERT INTO New_Table
        ('A','B_a','C','B_b','D','B_c','E')
        SELECT A, B, C, B:1, D, B:2, E
        FROM Table
        '''

import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('dbase_Sqlite')  # create or open db file
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute(query)
conn.commit()
curs.execute(query1)
conn.commit()
```

I got this error:

```
OperationalError: near ":1": syntax error
```

Apparently the ":1" and ":2" were added by the sqlite JOIN or UNION earlier. How should i deal with it?

Comment: I've removed the tags [tag:mysql] and [tag:postgresql] as this question is not about them.

Comment: Is the host language [tag:python] by any chance?

Comment: I am using python3, using sqlite3.connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer here, escaping the column names by giving "" to all column names in the query. It works.

```
query1 = '''
        INSERT INTO New_Table
            ('A','B_a','C','B_b','D','B_c','E')
        SELECT "A", "B", "C", "B:1", "D", "B:2", "E"
        FROM Table
        '''
```

Reference: https://blog.christosoft.de/2012/10/sqlite-escaping-table-acolumn-names/